# javahl subclipse 64 bit installation on windows

Tags: eclipse, 64-bit, subclipse, javahl

Got

- Windows 7 - 64 bit
- Eclipse indigo
- Java VM 64 bit
- javahl from http://www.sliksvn.com (64 bit version) properly installed
- path environment variable points also to the folder containing javahl librarires

When installing subclipse, I'm getting

> Incompatible JavaHL library loaded.  1.6.x or later required.

What should I do to get subclipse properly working ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The message should have said 1.6.x required. You probably installed SlikSVN 1.7.x. Just install Subclipse 1.8 which is designed for SVN 1.7. It also includes the JavaHL 64-bit binaries now.

Comment: Does SlikSVN 1.7.x requires SVN 1.7 on the server side ?  I got the impression that if we upgrade our server side subversion to 1.7, all the clients have to upgrade also.

Comment: I meant SlikSVN 1.8 in my previous comment.

Comment: No the SVN server and client do not need to be the same version.

Comment: Thanks.  it works.  I don't know if this makes a difference, but I had installed a 32 bit eclipse.  restarting from scratch, keeping everything 64 bit - with the right subclipse resolved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I think the preferred solution is to upgrade to subclipse 1.8 if possible. If you can't do that (e.g., because other dependencies like m2e-eclipse are still using subclipse 1.6), then you just need to install an earlier (1.6) version of SlikSVN x64.

For instance, you can get:
http://www.sliksvn.com/pub/Slik-Subversion-1.6.17-x64.msi.
which did the job for me when SlikSVN 1.7.1 (current as of this writing) failed with the exact error provided in the original question.

Just strip the MSI off the URL to see a list of previous releases:
http://www.sliksvn.com/pub/

Comment: The suggestion from Mark did work, but your approach is good to know.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd say this answer is the best one +1

Answer (score 0):

You might try to run Eclipse with "run as administrator" during the install. I have noticed that otherwise part of the install goes to wrong folders.

Comment: tried that one also ... where should the javahl libraries sit.  Got it now under c:\development\silksvn\bin